# tag subscriptions don't work

Tags: support

As of now, there's no way to subscribe to tags - the normal subscribe option fails and the manual subscription page (e.g for [jazz](http://stackexchange.com/tagsets/subscribe?tags=jazz&site=musicfans.stackexchange.com)) gives a 404. Is that just because the site is too new?

Comment: Probably.  Access to this site is restricted right now for the private beta, and as far as I'm aware those stackexchange.com features are not doing any fancy filtering to check whether you're allowed to see the feed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you elaborate on "the normal subscribe option fails"? I just tried it and it seems to be working fine - hover over the tag, click "subscribe", get email confirmation, click the link in the email, profit.

The "manual subscription page" link you tried isn't a valid URL, so it 404s as expected.

You can also set up the filter (read: subscription) manually at http://stackexchange.com/filters/.

Comment: Seems to have been a hickup that's now fixed.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Glad to hear it. :)